# how to prevent a theme from using templates of a sub themes (placed inside the parent theme dir)?

Tags: theming, subsites

my folder structure looks something like this:

```
 themes
└─  foo
   ├─  bar
   │  ├─  templates
   │  │  └─  node.html.twig
   │  └─  bar.info.yml
   ├─  templates
   │  └─  page.html.twig
   ├─  foo.info.yml
   └─  foo.libraries.yml
```

now I run a multisite. one site is using the `foo` theme and the other uses `bar`.

The site using the `foo` theme also invokes the template
`/theme/foo/var/templates/node.html.twig`

1. Why is that so?
2. I thought the `foo` theme only invokes templates inside its own `templates` folder? I expected this to be the point of the `templates` folder. Is that assumption wrong?
3. can I prevent this behavior without moving the subtheme somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes are not allowed to be placed inside one another, as oppose to modules. Even though it works, there are undesired side effects.

Answer (score 0):

This directory structure is shows one single theme called `foo`. The sub-directory `bar` has no meaning at all for Drupal, it is below `/themes/foo`and as such part of `foo`.

Your node file has to go into `/themes/bar/templates/OPTIONAL/SUBDIR/DOES/NOT/MATTER/node.html.twig`

Every theme, even subthemes, has to go in it's own `/theme`-directory. Please red [read the docs for sub-themes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme).

Comment: How and where do the docs answer the question?

Comment: The very first words on the sub-themes docs page are _"Sub-themes are just like any other theme"_. As your main theme `foo` already has a correct file and folder structure, it seems you already know how to create a theme. Do the same with the sub-theme, but add the `basetheme`key in the YAML